# How to automate the push of CreateOptions of Azure Docker image?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-iot-edge

I am new to Azure and IotEdge.

I have a `docker-compose` project with some `volumes` and `bindings` in `docker-compose.yml`.

I can build and push images to Azure Container Registry with no error.

When I want to deploy the modules to an `IoTEdge` device using `Set Modules` option when entering the device page, I need to set `Create Options` manually and set what I already set in `docker-compose.yml` for `volumes` and other stuff.

- Is there a way to automate this step ?
- Am I missing something ?

My purpose is:

1. My `IoTEdge` device gets provisioned automatically with `x509 DPS`
2. My modules are set in a `Deployment` with a tag
3. My `IoTEdge` device has some tag that matches the deployment
4. All my modules get deployed automatically after `DPS`.

I cannot automate the 4 steps when I must set `Create Options` manually in each module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you wish to have your custom module containers created with additional attributes such as mounted volumes, binds, etc.

One way this can be achieved is using the Set Modules page on the Azure IoT Portal for that Edge device. One of the tabs on the add module page is Container Create Options. In that section you can provide additional create options. The format of that section is exactly the same as the JSON you would pass to the Docker Engine REST API (https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.42/#tag/Container/operation/ContainerCreate). You are only interested in the HostConfig section. Here is an example of a custom module that binds a directory and exposes a port:

```
{
    "HostConfig": {
        "Privileged": true,
        "Binds": [
            "/home/iotedge-user/node-red:/data"
        ],
        "PortBindings": {
            "1880/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostPort": "1880"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.